# HERON'S FORMULA: A Geometric Proof

Tags: euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation

I've found a geometric proof of Heron's formula here [LINK](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Heron/Heron2/Heron2.html) and I have trounble with undestanding why three parts of $AY$ segment are equal $s-b$, $s-a$ and $s-c$. How to derive it?

Comment: Very nice geometric proof. Are you aware, on the other side, of the purely algebraic (and simple) proof of Heron's formula via Cayley Menger determinant (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronsFormula.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the three points of tangency between the incircle and $\Delta ABC$.  We already have $X$ labeled, let $W$ be the tangent point on $BA$ and $V$ the one on $BC$.

We will repeatedly use the fact that the two tangents drawn from a fixed point to a fixed circle have the same length.  Thus, $AX=AW$ and so on.  We denote:  $$AX=\lambda=AM\;\;BW=\mu=BV\;\;CV=\nu=CX$$

Note:  you are trying to show that $\lambda = s-a$ and so on.  We'll just show that one (the others are similar).

Inspection then shows that $$\lambda+\nu = b$$  $$\lambda+\mu=c$$ $$\mu+\nu=a$$  Adding the first two gives $$2\lambda +(\mu+\nu)=b+c\implies 2\lambda =b+c-a$$  from which your desired result follows at once.